# Improper scanning in C

Tags: c

I want to scan a character immediately after scanning a long type in C.But it fails when I use this code.It scans properly only if I define a separate scanning function for character.Can anyone tell me why it is so?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    scanf("%d%ld%c", &a, &b, &c);
    scanf("%f%lf", &d, &e);
    printf("%d\n%ld", a, b);
    printf("\n%c\n%.3f\n%.9lf", c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
```

**Output:**

```
3
12345678912345

0.000
0.000000000
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You need spaces between elements you're reading in the `scanf` call. Also, C, not C++.

Comment: I wonder how many dups of this there are?

Comment: I wonder if the `'%c'` actually read the `space` *"character immediately after scanning a long type in C"*?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's precisely the problem.

Comment: The comment was somewhat a tongue-in-cheek suggestion as opposed to an actual quandary `:)`

Comment: @AntonH Spaces are **not** needed  between elements in the scanf aside from `"%c"` should be`" %c"`.

Comment: @Bavya Step 1: test the return value from `scanf()` to gain insight into the problem.  Does `scanf("%f%lf", &d, &e);` return 2?  Does `scanf("%d%ld%c", &a, &b, &c);` return 3?

Comment: @chux I did not know that. The more you know ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    c      Matches  a  sequence  of characters whose length is specified by
>           the maximum field width (default 1); the next pointer must be  a
>           pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the char‐
>           acters (no terminating null byte is added).  The usual  skip  of
>           leading  white  space is suppressed.  To skip white space first,
>           use an explicit space in the format.
> ```

```
 3 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
                 ^
```

The %c in your code matches the first space character following "12345678912345". That leaves the "a" to match with %f. It is not a match so the second scanf() call fails (and returns 0 for no matches).

```
RETURN VALUE
       These  functions  return the number of input items successfully matched
       and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
       event of an early matching failure.
```

As pointed out in the comments above, your problem goes away if you add a space to your format string before the %c - it will then skip the whitespace and match on the 'a'. Then the pointer will move past the 'a' and the second scanf will work correctly.

```
int number_matched;
number_matched = scanf("%d%ld %c", &a, &b, &c)
```